# Django - Forms creation and handling issue

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm writing a Django website and I don't actually know which is the best way to organize my Models/Forms fields...

I basicall have the following strtuccture (the names are invented):

Model **CarCompany**:
name = CharField ....

Model **Car**:
name = CharField ....
company_name = ForeignKey ....

Model **Customer**:
name = CharField ....
surname = CharField ....

I need to save my model instances making sure there is an assosciation between the customer and all of his cars (and so also related cars.company_names) in the following way:

Model **CarDealer**:
name = CharField ....
custoom_field = [a list of all the possible assosciations between **Car** and **Customer**.

The way I thought it is to have a page that renders with the help of Ajax calls a series of rows and in each row I have three select element in which i can select in order: **Customer**, **CarCompany**, and (using AJAX), **Car**.

How can I handle at best this situation using Django Forms?

Comment: The usual way to record a many-to-one relationship (i.e. all of the cars owned by a specific customer) is with a foreign key.  And you're already using foreign keys, so I'm not sure what else you are asking for.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you need one model for **generic** cars, i.e. "Toyota Camry", and another model for **specific cars**, i.e. "this 2016 V6 Camry belongs to Bill, and that 2022 4-cylinder Camry belongs to Mary"?

Comment: It might be difficult to explain as I tried to use an example rather than the real situation. The problem is I don’t need to save a foreign key, a foreign key is one instance of a model on another model. I need to save a a field which ideally is made of two foreign keys. In my example I would need to save in the model CarDealers that would be a foreign key made of an istante of car and an instance of customer.

Comment: Let’s theoretically hypnotize a model named CarCustomer as a MTM field in carDealer model. My question is… imagine having a MTM field of CarCustomer… how would you handle it in a form? Is there a better way to handle this situation considering everything?

Comment: So you want to record all of the specific cars that a dealer has sold to a specific customer?

Comment: Almost, I want that someone who interacts with the website can select an integer (let’s name it choiceNumber) and for every choiceNumber the user can select a customer from the firsts select, can select a car company from the second and (using Ajax) can select a car from the third select, SUBMIT, and now Handel the form.is_valid()